# Is it better to let tables to be on top with tpb, or use "H"/"h"?

Tags: tables, floats

I am writing a thesis that has some occasional tables.

I cannot decide if it's "better" (both aesthetically and maybe in other regards) to just use the default "tpb" floating placement, which makes the tables to be "stacked" on top, or modify the placement using `\begin{table}[H]`.

Most scientific papers I have seen actually lets the table be on top and I am not entirely sure why. Are the tables easier to read, when they are stacked on top, usually far from the text that is referring to them?

(I am not asking about the technical issues of either approach, but more about aesthetics / practicality. I am aware this might be off topic for this site, but I have no idea where else on SE to ask this.)

Comment: Having floats at top or bottom avoids the problem of jumping over them when reading the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for having floats at all is to avoid large spaces at page breaks which are more or less inevitable if you use `H`. Whether saving on paper matters so much in a digital age is an interesting and somewhat controversial question, the answer to which affects how you should approach float positioning.  I'd use `H` as a last resort (and it was me that implemented it originally:-) you can use `[htp]` to allow it to be "here if it fits".

Comment: Since I am writing a school thesis, I want it to have as much pages as possible ;) but I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @KarelBílek If your optimization function is "page count", then the `lipsum` package may come in handy `;^O`